# ansible doesent assign jinja2 variable values

Tags: ansible, jinja2

the following task doesent work as expected. It should create an icinga2 config file on a remote host. It creates the file, but does not translate to the defined variables.

Ansible Task:

```
- name: create check for cq6-server
  template:
    src=icinga-cq6-template.j2
    dest=/etc/icinga2/zones.d/icinga.dus3/{{ ansible_hostname }}-cq6-{{ project_name }}-{{ cq_role_1 }}.conf
    mode=0644
  when: "'cq6-servers' in group_names or 'cq6-dispatcher' in group_names"
  delegate_to: "{{ monitoring_server }}"
  notify: restart icinga2
```

It creates following file on Icinga2 Server:

```
{{ ansible_hostname }}-cq6-{{ project_name }}-{{ cq_role_1 }}.conf
```

This file has still all the brackets, even `{{ ansible_managed }}`

Does anyone have a clue why ansible does this, but works on other tasks/templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's recommended to use the yaml dict notation, i.e.

```
- name: create check for cq6-server
  template:
    src: icinga-cq6-template.j2
    dest: "/etc/icinga2/zones.d/icinga.dus3/{{ ansible_hostname }}-cq6-{{ project_name }}-{{ cq_role_1 }}.conf"
    mode: 0644
  when: "'cq6-servers' in group_names or 'cq6-dispatcher' in group_names"
  delegate_to: "{{ monitoring_server }}"
  notify: restart icinga2
```

however it's likely your variables are empty, so I suggest using debug to verify, e.g.

```
- debug:
    var: "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
```

Comment: You were right, it was indeed an undefined variable.